# Adding columns (from other tables) to the 'most recent notes for each user' query sql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables: [Run code snippet]

```html
<!--__________________________________________________-->
---------------------'notes' table-----------------------
<!--__________________________________________________-->
<table>

  <thead>
    <th>note_id</th>
    <th>note_date</th>
    <th>note_time</th>
    <th>writer_id</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2-05-2016</td>
      <td>08:37:05</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>14-05-2016</td>
      <td>11:44:01</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>14-05-2016</td>
      <td>07:57:35</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>26-05-2016</td>
      <td>15:02:22</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>27-05-2016</td>
      <td>11:39:04</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>


<!--__________________________________________________-->
---------------------'writers' table-----------------------
<!--__________________________________________________-->

<table>

  <thead>
    <th>writer_id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Jame</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Lame</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Shame</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

I want to display the only the newest notes in the following format:

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>note_date</th>
    <th>note_time</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>2-05-2016</td>
      <td>08:37:05</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>14-05-2016</td>
      <td>11:44:01</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jame</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>26-05-2016</td>
      <td>15:02:22</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lame</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>27-05-2016</td>
      <td>11:39:04</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

I currently have the following SQL query that correctly returns the latest notes (although I am getting both notes by Jane Doe, writer id 2 due to notes on the same date):

**NOTE: I am not concerned with the duplicate for now.**

```html
SELECT a.note_id, a.note_date, a.note_time
FROM notes a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT note_id, MAX(note_date) note_date
    FROM notes
    GROUP BY note_id
) b ON a.note_id = b.note_id AND a.note_date = b.note_date
```

I want to add the writers names to the query but have no Idea of how to add the join:

```html
(notes INNER JOIN writers ON notes.writer_id = writers.writer_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to add the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT w.name, n.*
FROM notes n INNER JOIN
     (SELECT note_id, MAX(note_date) note_date
      FROM notes
      GROUP BY note_id
     ) nn
     ON n.note_id = nn.note_id AND n.note_date = nn.note_date INNER JOIN
     writers w
     ON n.writer_id = w.writer_id;
```